# After installing RStudio server on CentOs Linux, Cannot Install Packages non zero exit status

Tags: r, linux, centos, rstudio

Have read and tried various solutions to what sound like similar problems including:

[Cannot install RStudio on CentOS 6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360158/cannot-install-rstudio-on-centos-6-4)

[installing package "sjstats" gives error non-zero exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010740/installing-package-sjstats-gives-error-non-zero-exit-status)

[Unable to install sandwich package: installation of package ‘sandwich’ had non-zero exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358976/unable-to-install-sandwich-package-installation-of-package-sandwich-had-non-z)

[installation of package ‘recharts’ had non-zero exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773622/installation-of-package-recharts-had-non-zero-exit-status)

I've installed RStudio on Linux Centos7.

I downloaded and installed both R and Rstudio as root user. After opening port 8787 I was able to visit the application in my browser and reach the login page. RStudio would not allow me to login with the root user so I created a new user 'rstudio' in the terminal `sudo adduser rstudio`, created a password for rstudio user and then was able to login.

R works till this point. I am able to use base R, save scripts etc all within Linux CentOs hosted RStudio within my browser.

However, when I try to install any package, I receive an error message e.g.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘covr’ had non-zero exit status
```

This happens for every and any package that I try to install.

I tried changing permissions to 777 on R directory within /home/rstudio/R. I did this as the original root user who downlaoded and installed R and RStudio, not as the new end user "rstudio".

This did not solve my problem.

I tried adding `dependencies = T` to all of my calls to `install.packages()` however that did not make a difference.

I suspect that it's a permissions issue. However, I also tried to install packages from within R on the command line and could not, even when I was SSHd in as root.

Not sure what other information to provide.

How can I install packages and overcome 'non zero exit status' from within my instance of Hosted RStudio?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0    yaml_2.2.0
```

Comment: Have you installed any development tools to allow you to compile packages? On Ubuntu you need to install `r-base-dev` to do this, I don't have any real experience with CentOS but some quick googling suggests `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"` might be needed.

Comment: Yes that was it, I had not installed r-devel on the CentOs server. Cheers!